# Vertical scrolling of CollectionView Sections with horizontal scrolling of each section

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I want to make something like the following [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QURlw.jpg).
the collection view should be scrollable in Vertical direction but i want multiple cells which would again be in one line and would be horizontally scrollable. Also scrolling at every section should be independent of every other section.
The section headers I am using is via the supplementary headers.
Can you please suggest any good way to achieve it?

Comment: What code have you written to do this? Don't just ask people to do it for you. Tell us what you've tried and what didn't work. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! Also see [Ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using a UICollectionView for the vertical scroll and, when I need horizontal scroll in it I just add a custom UICollectionViewCell, which has a nested UICollectionView in it set up for a horizontal scroll. The delegate methods and data source methods You can figure out depending on Your implementation.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply, but i was just thinking multiple collection views, wouldn't that be very memory hogging if i have multiple sections?

Comment: In my app I have more than 4-5 sections at time and everything works like a charm even with image pre-loading and stuff. With the new iOS 10 collection view prefetching it runs even better.

Answer (score 0):

This is easily achievable doing the following:
First create a TableView with 3 sections.
Then, add a Horiontal CollectionView in each of the tableView sections.

For using different dataSource, just add a tag to each of the collectionViews, and in the delegate methods just ask:

```
if(collectionView.tag == 0){
 //first Collection
}else if(collectionView.tag == 1){
 //second Collection
}else{
 //third collection
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply, but i was just thinking multiple collection views, wouldn't that be very memory hogging if i have multiple sections?

Comment: That depends on how much processing each collectionView does. I use to do this with 5 collectionView